# How do i get the source of an image that has been downloaded off the internet?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

In the app i'm working on, an image is displayed to the user which is gotten from a website.
I want the app to have an option to save the image to gallery. 
From what i figure, since the image is displayed on the screen (and hence, has already been 'downloaded' to the phone), i shouldn't have to download it again for saving it to the phone (essentially specifying the URL of the image on the website as the image's source).
Is there a way to get the get the source (path) of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote one app while ago, it was about testing downloading an image from the web and putting it into Image control. And what surprised me a lot - after first download an image I was able to turn off wifi and  after that image was still showing. I think WP7 have quiet good cache or something and maybe if U ask second time about the same URL U'll receive temporary file from cache instead downloading it again...

Answer (score 1):

I researched a bit and found out that once an image has been downloaded from a url, it isn't downloaded again and is retrieved from the cache automatically. So, that leaves my question answered.
You were correct kingsvid!